# fancytree passing argument to source option

Tags: fancytree

I would like to pass an argument to source ooption, so "42" should be passed to data.php as 2nd valus/key parameter.Thx.

HTML:

```
<div>id="tree" datadir="42"</div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var tree = $("#tree").fancytree("getTree");  
  $(function() {

    $("#tree").fancytree({
      source: $.ajax({
        url: "/data.php",
        data: {mode: "root", parent: tree.data.datadir},
        dataType: "json"
      })
    });
 });
</script>
```

Regards

ulus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that value using jQuery. See updated code below.

HTML:

```
<div id="tree" data-dir="42"></div>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#tree").fancytree({
      source: $.ajax({
        url: "/data.php",
        data: {mode: "root", parent: $("#tree").data("dir")},
        dataType: "json"
      })
    });
 });
</script>
```